# Insert peaks ( ' ' ) to a string in text file

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax, insert

I have the following problem:
i have a huge text file of data that i have to insert to a Mysql database.
The problem is that i should insert for every string the  `' '` symbol.
Ad example:

```
234 , ROSS GHIL 
345,  CARL LOGAN
345,  ANDREW LOG
...
...

...
```

it should be

```
'234' , 'ROSS GHIL' 
'345',  'CARL LOGAN'
'345',  'ANDREW LOG'
...
...

...
```

Cause the insert query wants the  `' '`

Is there any easy method to do this?

Comment: just add "\" in front of every ' , example insert into table(name) values("\'name\'");

Comment: the problem is that i can't insert manually cause the file has 3000 row. i' m searching something tool

Comment: create a csv file , and use this command in mysql : load data local infile 'content_db.csv' into table tablenmae fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' (Age,Name);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this tool: http://tools.perceptus.ca/text-wiz.php?ops=7

It's far from perfect but will probably work for your problem.

Comment: this helps me a lot. Ty

Answer (score 2):

I am not an awk guru, but for a simple file this should be enough:

```
awk -F "," '{print "\x27"$1"\x27,\x27"$2"\x27"}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did, was exporting all the data to EXCEL and use the 'text to columns'-option to delimeter the data based on the , symbol.

After that; take the first empty column and build up the statement you need; like:

```
=("'" & A1 & "','" & A2 & "'")
```